List of Italian podcasts / TV shows / movies / TV series
Could we add sections of Italian podcasts, online TV shows and Netflix series/movies to What good reference works on Italian are available online? , as the ones already available at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/resources-for-learning-spanish-recursos-para-aprender-espa%c3%b1ol ? I watch Italian news on the RAI channel and Italian TV series/movies on Netflix and it's helping me a lot to learn Italian. I think it'd be helpful to other learners too.

I think it's an excellent idea, but I'm not sure that should be an answer to What good reference works on Italian are available online?.

I think this would be too long a list to be useful. Having a list of dictionaries made sense for meta, but this stretches the idea too much in my opinion.

@FedericoPoloni: Nevertheless, such a list has been made on Spanish.SE.

I don't think that the list would be that long either if the focus is on popular online content. For instance, how many Italian TV news broadcasts are available online? How many of those are free and available via streaming (clearly, the format which interests most people) ?

By coincidence I believe Raiplay is going through a revamp in these days (I'm not 100% sure, I don't follow much Italian TV)

I agree with @FedericoPoloni. Either we restrict drastically the scope of such a list, or anyone could chime in and mention their favourite Italian “podcasts / TV shows / movies / TV series” (and there are quite a lot of them). It would potentially be an infinite list, a heavily opinion-based one, and one hard to keep up to date (for instance, shows on Netflix come and go).

I think that the Spanish SE list is a very good model - as a format. This would be a good addition to the Meta.

I would suggest we talk over all this in bar sport

@Gio Maybe it's just me, but I prefer to be able to find out that I cannot understand spoken Italian as soon as possible and improving my listening skills little by little than only finding it out when I go to Italy. That's why I watch Italian TV series and movies (besides the fun factor, which stimulates learning).

@Easymode44 I would suggest we keep talking over all this here. That's what (meta) comments and answers are for. Chat is too cumbersome, transient, and difficult to search in my opinion.

@FedericoPoloni agreed. I am (very slowly) preparing an initial list with useful podcasts. What is particularly valuable in my opinion is not the list in and of itself but the captions I am adding. These can be used for a more targeted search depending on the learner's needs (slow diction, advanced vocabulary, Italian culture etc.)

@Easymode44: What about your list? I think it's better to write it as an answer here rather than one to the above mentioned post.

@Charo yes, the plan is to write it as an answer. Life is persistently getting in the way though :/
